# SQL 2012 Data importing and merging data

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am doing a project on database programming using `SQL Server 2012` and also visual studio. I have created some tables and I have a excel file with lots of data. The specification at this stage is to merge two excel sheets of data that has 11 columns each (same columns for both files with different data) into a separate table that is then used later on in the project for paging etc.

My original vision was to create two tables, one table that had one excel tab of data and another table exactly the same except for the name to house the second data set, and then using a union join to merge the two tables into one. However importing straight to the tables is impossible (possibly due to the existence of a composite key in column 1 of the data) so I then created two new tables altogether that now does contain the data from the excel sheets however this doesn't meet the specification of merging the files into the table (as the data is still in two tables not one, and also it has to be in a certain table that was created by DDL earlier). Also it doesn't solve the problem as there doesn't seem to be a way to query those tables into an existing table (or is there?)

Anyway, thanks for reading, hopefully I have included enough information, if it seems I've missed something, feel free to ask. I think the ideal solution for this would involve joins of some description such as union but there doesn't seem to be anyway to then relate that join back to the existing table.

Comment: So, you have two new tables imported from excel and you want to import this data into the one sql table?

Comment: I have imported the excel files into sql and the resultant data is saved as 2 tables alongside other tables already created (although it may just be easier to read the excel files directly again, not sure). 

So the question at hand is essentially how to get the data from 2 tables/excel into the 1 sql table, as retaining of Primary Key and data types is important.

Comment: What is the schema sql table that you will be importing into?

Comment: Haven't explicitly created any schema beyond actual tables, but in terms of the overall structure its an application of sorts, replicating functionality of facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will want to do something similar this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MainTable ON
INSERT INTO MainTable (col1, col2, col3 ... col11)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 ... col11
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 ... col11
FROM Table2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MainTable OFF
```

You haven't specifically mentioned you have an IDENTITY field for your Primary Keys but I'm assuming you are, hence including the SET IDENTITY_INSERT commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot my pacific friend (im from NZ)! this is pretty much exactly what I was after (although there still seems to be a problem joining the tables, mainly due to data standardisation)

Comment: No worries mate, glad that I could help you out. Yeah I'm pretty much a Samoan Kiwi, lived in NZ for most of my life but now in Oz :D

Comment: And boom I have finally worked through the data standardisation issues too, now on to the 'fun' stuff :) Thanks again. Mate what you doing over in that dustbowl? may as well return to the promised land again, people with any sort of sql skills can make a killing in wellington these days, although probably can make a killing anywhere as well :P

Comment: Sweet as bro, hopefully I'll be able to return and make a "killing" sometime but right now, Oz is the place to be to develop my skill set :D